# can a view embedded in a NavigationVC set as detail of splitVC poll from the master directly?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

my storyboard:

```
SplitViewController - NavigationController - (Master) CalculatorViewController
     I
NavigationController - (Detail) GraphViewController`
```

I am trying to setup a delegate from (Detail) that pulls data from the (Master) 
- but I can't seem to get the (Master) to set itself as the delegate:

I tried from the Detail view, in didLoad(): `graphView.calcDataSource = splitViewController?.viewControllers.first as CalculatorViewController` but it crashes by unwrapping a nil -

If I try to set `graphView.calcDataSource = self` in didLoad() on the Master side, I get `"Use of unresolved identifier graphView"`

What is the correct way to do it?

========

## SOLVED!

(with a storyboard segue on button called "Show Graph")

```
//CalculatorViewController.swift:
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue!.identifier == "Show Graph") {
        var yourNextViewController = (segue!.destinationViewController as UINavigationController)
        var detail = yourNextViewController.viewControllers[0] as GraphViewController
        var tempview = detail.view // FORCES THE VIEW object into existence, without this it will compile, but next line will crash at runtime (graphView nil)
        detail.graphView.calcDataSource = self
    }
}
```

note that **`var tempview = detail.view`** is critical here, despite not being used. I understand as it setting up the view and outlet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your code, I can't tell how your detail view is instantiated.  You can set the connection at the point where you instantiate your detail view.  When using storyboard, this is often done inside prepareForSegue.

Comment: new to swift, is there a simple way to figure out how the views are instantiated? (can't find any indication in code itself regarding the NavigationControllers or even the SplitViewController, those were both done in storyboard)

Comment: Look into adding prepareForSegue to your code.  Set a breakpoint there to make sure it's being hit and set up your master/detail connection there.

Comment: the Detail view is the first thing that shows up on the screen. From printouts, the CalculatorVC gets properly setup in the splitViewController but then it calls to the detail SOMEHOW .... I can't seem to figure out where that is happening, could it be from storyboard UISplitView? _to clarify_: I am not using any manually assigned segues, this is all coming from the storyboard.

Comment: We won't be able to help you much without looking at your code and setup.

Comment: how does one provide those when storyboard is involved?  (Is it even possible?)

Comment: With storyboard, you can take a screenshot.

Comment: Need 10 rep to post screenshots - it's taking a bit longer than expected. I'll keep working on it though - I managed to implement prepareForSegue() but it is seguing to a NavigationController wrapping a GraphingViewController ... tried `var yourNextViewController = (segue!.destinationViewController as UINavigationController)
            yourNextViewController.splitViewController?.delegate = self.splitViewController?.delegate` but it crashes on the segue. For some reason the Detail View seem to have only 1 VC inside the uiSplitViewController... while polling from Master has 2. Weird.

Comment: Thanks for the moral support Boon, I feel good about getting this to work!

Comment: @John It may be better to store the datasource in detail view controller, rather than view.  That's the responsibility of a view controller more so than a view, and you wouldn't have to do the thing you did with tempView.